# Removing submodule and keeping files?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am using a plugin that helped me tremendously but uses a submodule.
When I tried to push it to remote I learned that a submodule is just a reference to another repo.
I want to just have the files in my own repo and push them to remote.

All attempts from other SO articles have failed so far.

Here is my .submodules folder:

```
[submodule "Vendor/Opauth"]
    path = Vendor/Opauth
    url = git://github.com/opauth/opauth.git
```

Here is my filesystem for this specific area:
[image]

How do I remove the submodule and then keep the `Vendor/Opauth` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[How do I remove a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)", you should deinit and remove the submodule (assuming here git 1.8.3+).

```
git submodule deinit Vendor/Opauth
git rm --cached Vendor/Opauth
rm -Rf .git/modules/Opauth
```

The `--cached` ensure that you keep the files on the disk.

Comment: Thanks I saw your post earlier - problem is I get this:

`error: pathspec 'app/Plugin/Vendor/Opauth' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?`

Comment: @itamar but if the submodule path is `Vendor/Opauth`, shouldn't the `git rm` uses `Vendor/Opauth` from the `Plugin` folder?